# How to make the code wait for all of the requests to finish Android okhttp

Tags: java, android, multithreading, okhttp

```
        for(String number : numbers) {
            RequestBody formBody = null;

           ...


            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
               ....

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                   //blahblah
                }
            });

        }



here's the code that needs to wait for all of the responses above to arrive
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, PaidActivity.class);
        //blahblah
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
        context.finish();

    }
```

How to make this Intent wait for the callbacks above to finish? How to stop and proceed only after receiving all of the responses from the server?

Answer (score 1):

Just putting these codes of yours into the onResponse() method, will solve your issue. Oh, don't forget to check and wrap with `if(response.isSuccessful())`:

```
  if(response.isSuccessful()) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, PaidActivity.class);
    //blahblah
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
    context.finish();
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: nah it's not what I want. I want to wait for ALL of the responses to arrive before opening up the Activity.

Comment: This is very hard to understand your question by just checking a snippet of your code, If you have more network calls let us know first your current situation properly.
Well, now for your solution there is a little trick for you: If you know after how many calls, you want to go to the next activity, just increment count of them to ta desired response to be arrived. Like you want to go next activity when 3 apis respond successfully. A (global) `count++` in every `if(response.isSuccessful())` condition and check `if (count == 3)` navigate to next activity. Simple

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have some sort of counter keeping track of all of your requests and execute some code when they all finish. A quick and dirty solution would look something like this:

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(numbers.length);
for (String number : numbers) {
    RequestBody formBody = null;
    // ...
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        // ...

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            int currentCount = counter.decrementAndGet();
            if (currentCount <= 0) {
                // You might need to call this on the UI thread.
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, PaidActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
                context.finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I would recommend a more reactive approach using eg. [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) instead of an anonymous callback.